# LINQ contains on Nullable guid field

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, linq

I would like to pick the latest DataItem record for each *QuestionID* that is in the '*ids*' array. 
Because I cannot use **.Value** within LINQ I have converted the ids to *Nullable*. However I now get an **'Object must implement IConvertible'**

Table:DataItem

```
------------------------------------
ID                  |   Guid        |
DataItemTimeLocal   |   DateTime    |
QuestionID          |   Guid?       |
------------------------------------

Guid?[] ids = GetAllQuestions().Select(x => (Guid?)x.ID).ToArray();
var latestItems = (from di in DataObjects.DataItems
                       where di.QuestionID != null && ids.Contains(di.QuestionID)
                       group di by di.QuestionID into g
                       select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataItemTimeLocal).FirstOrDefault()
           ).ToDictionary(x => x.QuestionID, y => y);
```

Comment: you need to redesign your query so that you don't need to call Contains() inside it

Comment: why do the `ids` need to be nullable guids? just make an array of Guids and leave out the nulls, your query criteria (`di.QuestionID != null`) will discard them anyway.

Comment: @Adi: I already do this by iterating through ids and doing a query per question id which is inefficient and I am looking for a better way perhaps with a single query.

Comment: @paul: Yes di.QuestionID != null would discard but I still can't use the next part .Contains unless the ids are nullable

Comment: @user1984695 this is indeed very inefficient and it is not the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Guid[] ids = GetAllQuestions().Select(x => x.ID).ToArray();

var latestItems = (from di in DataObjects.DataItems
                   where di.QuestionID.HasValue && 
                         ids.Contains(di.QuestionID.Value)
                   group di by di.QuestionID into g
                   select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.DataItemTimeLocal)
                           .FirstOrDefault()
                   ).ToDictionary(x => x.QuestionID, y => y);
```

Comment: It throws an error. The member access 'Boolean HasValue' is not supported. I had the same issue with .Value earlier

Comment: @user1984695 looks like that's a problem of your mysql Linq provider. Works just fine both with Linq to Sql.